# How to change data on textview in a row of listview when I Click Button in the same row

Tags: android, listview

I have textview and button in the same row of listview. I want to click the button and then TextView "+1".How can i do?  The erro says "viewholder is access from inner class must be declared be final".

```
viewHolder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(viewHolder.countt.getText().toString());
        viewHolder.Textview.setText("" + a + 1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error gives you the solution, make viewholder **final**.

I would suggest store TextView in a final variable, **final TextView t = viewHolder.Textview;**

And then in your code just set the text with **t.setText("text")**

Comment: Thx i go try it now

Comment: does not work either.I have tried different way before.

Comment: Are you getting the same error ? Setting the final variable has to be outside and before the **setOnClickListener** call

Comment: yes same erro occur. sure out side setOnClickListener

Comment: I have try use some variable saved inside to the outside. But just does not work. There is no link from the insided to the Outside. This very confused me

Comment: Problem solved I set the viewpager=null; It is wrong.